# select all products and related products for a categoryid in sqlite

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have 2 tables: Products and ChildProducts.

I need to select all products for a given CategoryID AND the related ChildProducts that DO NOT have the same CategoryID

```
Products:
ItemID  CategoryID   Name
A          1         Test1
B          1         Test2
C          2         Test3
A1        0         Test4
A2        0         Test5
A3        0         Test6
B1        0         Test7
B2        0         Test8
C1        0         Test9
C2        0         Test10
C3        0         Test11
C4        0         Test12

Child Products:
ParentItemID    ChildItemID
A                     A1
A                     A2
A                     A3
B                     B1
B                     B2
C                     C1
C                     C2
C                     C3
C                     C4
```

So need all products whose parentItemID is in a given category, IE CategoryID=1 would return:

```
Results:
A         Test1
A1         Test4
A2         Test5
A3         Test6
B         Test2
B1         Test7
B2         Test8
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/0b874/15)

```
select p1.ItemID

from Products p1
LEFT JOIN ChildProducts cp on p1.ItemId=cp.ChildItemID
LEFT JOIN Products p2 on cp.ParentItemID=p2.ItemId


  where p1.CategoryId=1
        or 
        p2.CategoryId=1
ORDER BY COALESCE(p2.ItemID,p1.ItemID),p2.ItemId
```